# ESCAPE SEQUENCE NOT SUPPORT IN SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

My Table Contains

```
Id(int)  name(nvarchar(300))         path(nvarchar(3000))
--------------------------------------------------------------
8        Subunit1_1                  વસૂલાત/SubUnit/!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?,.;'[]\-=
```

my Query:

```
select * from tbl1 where Path = 'વસૂલાત/SubUnit/!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?,.;''[]\-='
```

I am Getting Empty Table.backslash and single quotes are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `N` prefix in your search string something like this...

```
select * from tbl1 
where Path = N'વસૂલાત/SubUnit/!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?,.;''[]\-='
```

Because you have these unicode characters in your strings, you need to tell sql server explicitly that string may contain some unicode character by prefixing it with `N`.

Same is true when you are inserting, updating unicode data in sql server.

### Your Updated Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSCS_ManageOrgunits]
@DomainId int,
@orgunitpath nvarchar(3000), 
@iDisplayStart int,
@iDisplayLength int
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF @orgunitpath = ''    
     BEGIN
            SELECT a.[row],a.OrgUnitId,a.did,a.OrgUnitName,a.OrgUnitPath,a.ScheduledStatus,a.AutoSyncStatus  
            FROM
            (            
                SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrgUnit_tbl.OrgUnitId) AS row,OrgUnitId,did,OrgUnitName,OrgUnitPath,ScheduledStatus,AutoSyncStatus  
                FROM     OrgUnit_tbl
                WHERE    did = @DomainId AND OrgUnitPath = @orgunitpath    
            ) AS a 
           WHERE a.[row] >= @iDisplayStart AND a.[row] < @iDisplayStart+@iDisplayLength     
     END
    ELSE
     BEGIN        
        SELECT  OrgUnitId,did,OrgUnitName,OrgUnitPath,ScheduledStatus,AutoSyncStatus  
        FROM    OrgUnit_tbl
        WHERE   did = @DomainId AND OrgUnitPath = @orgunitpath
     END

END
```

Comment: hi M.Ali, i am using store procedure i am Not able to  give N "WHERE  did=@DomainId AND OrgUnitPath = N+@orgunitpath"-->getting error Invalid Column name

Comment: Well now you are asking a different question. Well in case of stored procedure parameters just make sure your Parameters are of appropriate data type i.e NVARCHAR, NCHAR which will allow unicode data to be stored in them. and you are good to go.

Comment: hi Mr.Ali,My Stored Procedure Parameters are already in nvarchar datatype

Comment: Post your stored Procedure Definition in your question

Comment: Have a look I have updated your procedure, you had a lot of unnecessary stuff in there. I have cleaned it up a little bit. You dont need a temp table at all for this simple select statement, Also you dont need it to be NVARCHAR(MAX) I have made some changes it should work now.

Comment: hi Mr.Ali I am Doing Calculation I have Updated My Procedure Please Take a view http://justpaste.it/arunk28

Comment: In my answer look above in answer window :)

Comment: hi Mr.Ali Please See my Full Procedure  I am Doing Calculation So only Used Temp Tables.Please Use "Just Paste it" For Update the Procedure

Comment: Hi M.Ali, please give solution how to use prefix "N" in that above procedure with parameter @orgunitpath